# Keeping chosen option on dropdown selected after page change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

So I've built my first responsive site but having issues with the menu on the mobile device. It all works so that when your using the mobile you can select an option from the dropdown (HTML below) and it will take you off to the correct page. However when the page loads it defaults back to 'Home' Which is the first option in the list.

This means you can't select home when you are on another page. But what I need is when the option is selected and the new page loads for the one selected to then become the default option. So you can go back to the homepage using the drop down.

I've not done this before, so hoping it's fairly simple!

HTML:

```
 <form id="mobile_nav">
            <select id="mobile_menu">

<option value="/">Home</option>           
<option value="/page 1/">page 1</option>
<option value="/page 2/">page 2</option>
<option value="/page 3/"page 3</option>
<option value="/page 4/"page 4</option>
<option value="/page 5/"page 5</option>

            </select>
 </form>
```

JS:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        nav();

          jQuery("#mobile_menu").val(location.pathname);

        jQuery("#mobile_menu").change(function() {
            document.location = jQuery(this).val();
        });
```

The JS enables the dropdown on the mobile device.

Let me know if you need anymore info and thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#mobile_menu").val(location.pathname)
});
```

This will attempt to set the value of `#mobile_menu` same as the path portion of location (current URL).

Comment: Thank you very much. The pathname worked better than href as it didn't need to get the whole URL. I'll update the answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can know the current URL using `document.URL`. Comparing this URL with the values in dropdown, you can select respective option when the page loads.
For eg. You can use an approach similar to this:

```
var currentURL = document.URL;
if (currentURL.indexOf("home"))
{
   $("#mobile_nav select").val("home");
}
```

Comment: Would that mean i'd have to do an if statement for each option in the dropdown?

Comment: yep. or if your value is the same as the URL, you can use `$("#mobile_nav select").val(document.URL);`

Answer (score 0):

use `window.location.href` to get the current location and select that

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#mobile_menu").val(window.location.href);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

My knowledge in that area is out of date, but this may bring some idea (I hope).

```
<head>
  <script>
    function makeDefault(elm) {
        elm.options[elm.selectedIndex].selected = 'selected';
        alert(elm.innerHTML);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="mobile_nav">
    <select id="mobile_menu" onchange="makeDefault(this)">
      <option value="/">Home</option>           
      <option value="/page 1/">page 1</option>
      <option value="/page 2/" selected='selected'>page 2</option>
    </select>
  </form>
</body>
```